# I'm developing a WordPress theme and using custom fields. I'm facing the following problem

Tags: wordpress, image, templates, wordpress-theming, theme-development

My code

```
 <`li><img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_for-gallery', true); ?> " alt=""></li>`
```

The code should give this:-

```
 <img src="Array" alt="" draggable="false">
```

But the code is giving this:-

```
<img src=" " alt="" draggable="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code reference for `get_post_meta()` - it says that the function will return an array if the 3rd parameter (`$single`) is `false`:

> Return: (mixed) An array if $single is false. The value of the meta
> field if $single is true. False for an invalid $post_id.

In your code you're sending `true`, try this instead:

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, '_for-gallery', false);
```

More info here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: Thanks for the replay. But when I send "false" it shows:- `<img src="<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\comet\wp-content\themes\comet-2021\formats\content-gallery.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
Array " alt="" draggable="false">`

Comment: That's a good thing! it means that you do get an array response that way :) If you want to see what's inside, try: $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_for-gallery', false); print_r($post_meta);

Answer (score 0):

When you use `get_post_meta` function with $single as true just get the first element, but false get all elements separated by comma.

Looking your code, i suppose that custom_field is an url, in that case, why you need get an array as a url? you must get a string...

You can check here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/